# bash string to int

Tags: bash, string

Here is what I tried doing:

```
#!/bin/sh
res=`df | awk 'FNR == 2 { print $5 }'`
res2=$((res+0))
```

Here is my error:

> -bash: 53%: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "%")

I Googled 'string to int bash' which showed me `$((res+0))` but it doesn't work due to the `%` in the string (`53%`). How do I convert it in such a way I can do an if statement such as the one below (but that works)?

```
if [ "$res2" -ge 50 ]
then
    echo "Your disk >=50% full!"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let awk do it:

```
df -P | awk 'NR == 2 { print $5+0; exit }'
```

Comment: Nice! Like bash, awk also stores even numerical values as strings. But this works because when a variable is used in a numerical context, awk strips off any trailing non-numerical junk. (It would also strip off any leading spaces, if $5 happened to contain some. When you use the default field-separation, though, $5 won't.)

Answer (score 2):

Just tell awk to suppress the `%`:

```
#!/bin/sh
res=`df | awk 'FNR == 2 { sub("%","",$5); print $5 }'`
res2=$((res+0))
```

But I don't see that the `res2` line does anything. Unless you have `declare -i res2`, bash is still going to treat it as a string. You can do the following just fine:

```
if [ $res -ge 50 ]; then
    echo "Your disk >= 50% full!"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

A little variable manipulation would also do:

```
res=`df | awk 'FNR == 2 { print $5 }'`
limit=50

if ((  ${res%\%} > limit )); then
    echo "Your disk >= ${limit}% full"
fi
```

`${res%\%}` will remove the last occurrence of % from `res`, (the first % means remove last occurrence and then you need to escape \% to say that's the pattern to be removed)